# Recommended builds for Geth Engineer

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

With the new resurgence DLC, the Geth Engineer was introduced.  What are some good builds for the Geth Engineer?  How do builds differ depending on play for Bronze difficulty versus Gold difficulty?

Answer (score 3):

I've been playing the Geth Engineer almost exclusively for the last few days and have some tips for Bronze/Silver and then Gold.

### Role

The Geth Engineer can be an extremely valuable support teammate with its ability to provide extremely helpful map awareness, crowd control and healing. On lower difficulties you can spec the Geth to just be a massive offensive killing machine.  Both support and offensive sample builds will be provided below

**Gold/Support Build**

Geth Engineers can be absolute powerhouses on Bronze/Silver, but in Gold they are best suited for support and can offer one of the only "healing" abilities in the game.

Abilities:  Geth Turret/Geth Hunter/Overload/Net AI/Advanced Hardware

**6/6/6/4/4**

1. Geth Turret spec'ed to provide AOE Healing. At levels 4-6: Damage & Shield, Range & Heal, Frequency
2. Hunter Mode spec'ed to have cooldown reductions and increased power damage. Hunter mode will reduce shields so in higher difficulties you'll be using your turret as a "base" and be sure to disable when under life-threatening attack.  Hunter Mode being active grants many weight/power/and damage bonuses that allow you to carry normally heavier/limiting weapons and still maintain an extremely efficient cooldown.
3. Overload Spec'ed to Radius(AoE), Cooldown, and Shield Damage.  Extremely spammable, stuns most enemies setting up easy headshots, and can wipe out All but the strongest enemy shields in one shot. Additionally able to combine with other abilities to provide a "Tech Burst".  EXTREMELY useful.
4. AI with Power and Capacity
5. Adv. Hardware with Health and Shield perks

**Bronze/Silver Build**

This build is based around just walking around and using Hunter Mode to see enemies and stun/distract them with Overload/Offensive Turret while you unload on them with a pistol or rifle. Typically you fire the turret off where you are holding/attacking and then spam overload while you set up bursts and headshots.

**6/5/6/4/5**

1. Turret spec'ed to: Damage & Shield, DPS & Armor, Frequency
2. Hunter Mode spec'ed to cooldown bonuses to allow for quick overload spam and constant turret availability.
3. Overload spec'ed for Damage, Cooldown, and Shield Damage.
4. AI with Power and Capacity
5. Hardware with Heath and Shield, Shield Recovery

### Weapons

For Gold I'd recommend The Falcon for an assault rifle with Extended Barrel & Extended Magazine if possible.  You want the DPS here.  Additionally, Disrupter/Cryo Ammo and Rail Mods will definitely help out at higher difficulties.

Additionally you can substitute the Falcon for a Pistol like the Phalanx or Carnifex.  Having those pistols at higher levels definitely helps.  Attachments follow the Falcon suggestions.

On Bronze/Silver, I typically use the Pistol with magazine and barrel mods.  You can play around with/practice with any ammo mods, but once know what to expect I'd save them for Gold runs.

If you use a microphone, Geth Hunter mode can be a life saver with your ability to see through walls, smoke, and cloaks.  Play around with these builds and find the style that suits you.

Answer (score 1):

I just recently promoted my Geth Engineer because I had put 6 points into Hunter Mode but didn't like it. I found that the 50% reduction in shields wasn't worth the benefits, as I was dying quite frequently on Silver and unable to help my team (plus the overlay on the screen is distracting as well).

Here's my new build that I've found works much better for my playstyle:

> Geth Turret: 6 (Shield Restore, Restore Range, Restore Frequency)
>
> Hunter Mode: 0
>
> Overload: 6 (Chain Overload, Recharge Speed, Shield Damage)
>
> Networked AI: 6 (Weapon Damage, Power Damage, Weapon Damage)
>
> Advanced hardware: 6 (Durability, Shield Recharge, Fitness Expert)

I play a support role with this build, using overload to remove shields and stun enemies whenever it's available, and placing my turret next to allies so that it is constantly refilling their shields. For weapons, I bring the Geth Plasma Shotgun. It does excellent damage, has very long range and benefits from the Networked AI bonus to Geth weaponry. For attachments I use spare thermal clips and extended barrel. I don't take a second weapon because it means less delay between overloads.

I hope this helps!

Comment: 100% Agreed with the 6/0/6/6/6 Build. The hunter mode isn't worth it guys. Trust me. Even offensive as defensive is better without that crap thing, Some people lag because of that foolish overlay, Just leave it at 0.

Answer (score 1):

My Geth Engineer Code Name "I Pod"

Powers Layout:

Geth Turret: Level 6 (Maxed Out)

It’s all about the shield Regen here Max it out for amount and distance with recharge rate. (all across the bottom on the powers list)

Geth Turret Tactics Self: Everywhere you mover that turret either precedes you (meaning you launce it there before you move) or is placed in a safe spot (not out in the open) FYI the turret WILL recharge you through a wall or cover.

Geth Turret Tactics Team: Vital during missions as it will not only protect a buddy but recharge his/her shield while they are busy during a shut down/power up mission. Hack missions the Geth Turret is a LIFE SAVING ACT OF AWSOMNESS, if done so as above instructed, every 3-4 seconds someone is receiving 700 shields. When attempting to revive a fallen person shoot the turret right on top of them, this will 1 instantly recharge their shields when they are raised or 2 assist you by recharging your shields when raising the fallen if you’re taking heavy fire.

Hunter Mode: Level 6 (Maxed Out)
At the 4th, 5th and 6th Power options go all across the bottom. (Increasing accuracy, fire rate and damage)

Hunter Mode Tactics Self:  Besides the obvious benefits (being able to see Hunters, and through smoke and walls, Phantoms ECT.)  The increased Accuracy (+15%) Fire Rate (+15%) Damage (+10%) Allows you do dish out amazing amounts of damage, with one weapon in particular the Phaeston assault rifle. Now you may be thinking I like the Avenger or the Geth Pulse Rifle (Due to the fact that geth get a little boost in damage for using it in powers later on, and bullet travel time causes an issue Pheaston’s bullets hit instantly while it seems to take the Pulse Rifles longer to reach the target) or some other rifle breed better. I have tried EVERY other rifle and Sub Machinegun in the game and the Pheaston is by far (that means without any doubt) the best choice, it even outshines the geth shotgun in damage over time due to the insane accuracy. (Shooting a Trooper in the face from across the map, oh while out of cover)

Hunter Mode Tactics Team: Besides being able to just tell your teammates where the dangers are or what’s coming (usually hunters or cloaked Phantoms)  Using Incendiary ammo  will allow them to see what it is you see when you shoot them (hunters and Phantoms visibly “pulse” allowing everyone to see them) if you’re playing with random’s that don’t have (or are just too dumb to not use) a headset.

Overload: Level 4

I love overload, as in don’t want to live without it but since you can’t max everything… Set it to Level 4 where it jumps and hits an additional target within 8 meters.

Overload Tactics Self/Team: Obviously not as effective as a max version but it will drop shields off the intended target (Marauder, Centurions, Rocket troopers) and arch off and zap another. The main benefit here is the “stun effect” on unshielded enemies (Cerb and Geth Troopers, Cannibals) causing them to take a little damage and stand still. Since you did like I told you and Spec’d Hunter Mode (right?) dropping both stunned targets  very quickly.

Networked AI: Level 4

Networked AI’s power and damage boosts do nothing for 1 Hunter Mode or 2 how much shields Geth Turret gives you so the only thing you miss out on is really +10% Weapon and +5% Geth Weapon Damages (weight reduction is nice but a Phaeston X’s rate of charge is 160% and it’s a silver card weapon so if you buy enough Veteran Packs (20,000 Credits each) you’ll get it fast)

Advanced Hardware: Level 6 (Maxed)

Since Hunter Mode half’s your shields its all +health and shield and +shields recharge rate (all across the bottom)

Recommended Weapon, Mods and Equipment:

Phaeston (I to X) with a Piercing Mod (Extended Barrel if using Armor Piercing Ammo) and a Stabilizer

Equipment: Incendiary Ammo (or Armor P. Ammo)) + Assault Rifle Damage (or Targeting VI)+ Power Modulator

This Build type crushes on Silver and does quite well on Gold too, I've never played it on Bronze but I think you should be fine.

Look me up on Xbox Live, Tag Name: U Bite My Pill0